# Extract search results from external url using Electron cross platform?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, atom-editor

I'm intending to create an app using electron to extract data from a website and save it in a DB. This website is similar to google(an input and a search  button, but no API) instead in addition requires for the first search to introduce a captcha code. My concern is to find out what's the simple way to automatize the process of sending requests and collecting the results. Can be Selenium a way or there is no need of other extensions to achieve it? Please offer me advice?(I don't have Electron experience)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't express myself in an understandable way. What I need is to create an app to collect information from a website similar to google.com. Firstly I decided to use Electron because I have JS experience and secondly I would like to experience it's features. The website requires one time captcha until to start searching items, but I think I can pass the captcha by inserting it manually, loading that website in a webview or modal. And then start an automated search of my items(>10000 items). At the moment I'm struggling to select DOM pieces from the webview.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I don't completely understand the problem.
You want to scrap data from a website. But why you want to do so with Electron?
You can do it with selenium in a lot of different ways (and languages), using the drivers (like chromedriver).

The question is about Electron and Selenium or about how to avoid captcha and automatize the process?

In the first case, you can follow:
https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/using-selenium-and-webdriver.md

In the other case, it depends from the website and from a lot of other things.

**PS: If I set up a captcha, it's because I don't want that someone scrap my data :)**

Comment: I added a comment to my question to improve its clarity. I started to use <webview> în order to achieve my goal.